# Php: Too many levels of symbolic links?

Tags: php

While using "composer", I am getting following error:

> "php: Too many levels of symbolic links".

The path for php is /usr/bin/php.

Comment: run this and post output: `$ sudo find / -name "*php*"`

Comment: does this post help at all? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141436/too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links

Comment: Not really ? I'm still getting same error.